# Flutter ImageIcon showing image white or black

Tags: flutter

So I have been trying to use a picture I have stored in assets and use it as a logo. This way I can animate the logo rather then just having it as a static picture. But the logo keeps showing up just white or when I tried to wrap it and set the colors to null then it shows it all black. So wondering how I get it to show my original image.

```
new IconTheme(
data: new IconThemeData(
  color: null,
),//IconThemeData
  child: new ImageIcon( new AssetImage("images/logo.png"), color: null, size: _logoAnimation.value * 200),//Logo

),//IconTheme
```

Comment: I am having the same issue even after setting the color to null. Can you display the working code?

Comment: I am facing the same issue as post owner and @Claude. I have opened an issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81643

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This happens because, the `IconThemeData` returned by `IconTheme.of` method is merged with `IconThemeData.fallback()` which has a default color as black.

You can look [`here`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon_theme.dart#L62) to know what actually the `IconTheme.of` method returns and the `IconThemeData.fallback()` just returns [`this`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/icon_theme_data.dart#L28).

You can raise an issue regarding the same [`here`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues).

As a workaround, you can just do what `ImageIcon` does with color as null.

Example:

```
new Image(
  image: new AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
  width: _logoAnimation.value * 200,
  height: _logoAnimation.value * 200,
  color: null,
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried setting to null like you suggested, it is still black icon for an image. Can you please provide and working example?

Comment: I'm suggesting to use the above solution of using the `Image` instead of `ImageIcon`. If you try to user `ImageIcon` with `color:null` the won't work.

Comment: @HemanthRaj: the problem with using `Image` instead of `ImageIcon` is that it significantly enlarges the display of the icon. Since this didn't achieve what I was looking for, I have created an issue
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81643

Comment: @kamalbanga , actually the `ImageIcon` internally is doing the same as what I've posted here, if you're conserned about the size, give the `width` and `height` of the image as the `iconSize` from the `IconTheme`.

Comment: You saved my life Mr Hemanth Raj ! Thank you !