# How to set custom icons

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

Currently, I am trying to use my own image for an icon using

```
 ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets\icon\logo.png")
                      )
```

But this pops up
[image]

My logo is in
[image]
and I copied relative path

Comment: Did you put the path to your icon in pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 4):

Change the slash

```
ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icon/logo.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

add your image to `pubspec.yaml` as an assets

[image]

an also you use wrong slash . it should be like below

- change this

```
ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets\icon\logo.png"))
```

- to this

```
ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icon/logo.png"))
```

Comment: It's just a black square now.

Comment: @pika3113 you need to `flutter run` again, so the image can be loaded  from assets

Comment: I did that.....

Comment: its caused by `IconTheme.of` ,

Comment: @pika3113  for workaround just use  `Image`  instead. 
here the reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/49168837/12838877

Comment: Where can i find ```IconTheme.of```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247193/discussion-between-pika3113-and-pmatatias).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the icon inside IconButton in app bar actions then this worked for me:

```
IconButton(
  icon: Image.asset(
    "images/your_icon.png",
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

So maybe try:

```
IconButton(
  icon: Image.asset(
    "assets/icon/logo.png",
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

I put the icon inside `images` folder in root folder, and Added the icon in `pubspec.yaml` as the other answers said.

```
flutter:
  assets:  
    - images/your_image.png
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're importing a local image or any other package, make sure to add it in **pubspec.yaml** file.

In your case, you should add it in **'assets:'** under ***'flutter:'*** in **pubspec.yaml**

[image]

After that, when you're calling it in your dart file, **make sure you use the / for file path.**

[image]

*Hope it helps! Happy Fluttering :)*